# mismatch with python version

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm confused with the python version I'm using (under `Ubuntu`):

I'm using `pycharm`.
In pycharm I'm using python `3.6.8` (checked with `pycharm` terminal `python --version`)

When I'm working from linux terminal (not `pycharm` terminal) and I'm checking the version I'm getting:

```
3.7.6
```

I checked which python versions I'm using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
* 2 /usr/local/bin/python 3.6 0 manual mode
```

when checking:

```
python which:
/home/userA/miniconda3/bin/python
```

1. Why the terminal shows 3.7.6 version
   while I set the 3.6 version ?
2. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Hi, in the terminal, can you do `which python` . This will show you what python terminal is using

Comment: /home/userA/miniconda3/bin/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed anaconda python version for the user instead of globally. You can try to rectify this by uninstalling miniconda3 on this user. Or using `virtual env` created from your desired python version.

This can be achieved by using running following command with absolute path of your desired python library

```
/usr/local/bin/python -m venv <dir_name>
```

for more Info, Check out this reference on virtual env

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments

Answer (score 0):

Print python version from linux command line with

```
python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])))'
```